# Drop or not import a RasterLayer within a RasterStack that does not have values in all cells

Tags: r, r-raster

I have a RasterStack with 17 RasterLayers. Some rasterlayers do not, however, include the entire area of interest, I would like to eliminate RasterLayers that do not have data at every point in the area of interest.

Here are some photos of the problems

Complete RasterLayer
[image: Complete RasterLayer]

Non-Complete RasterLayer
[image: Non-Complete RasterLayer]

Could you help to avoid those RasterLayers and get a complete RasterStack?

Comment: Can you please create a reproducible example with some data generated by code? (see the help files of the raster package for ideas).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach with "terra" (the replacement of "raster")

Example data

```
library(terra)
s <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))   
s[[2]][1:1000] <- NA
```

Solution

```
g <- unlist(global(s, "notNA"))
i <- max(g)
x <- s[[g==i]]
```